# Prove that $\sigma^2=R^2$

Tags: volatility

Suppose we have the following series: $R_1$, $R_2$, ...., $R_N,$ which are returns of a stock for $t=1,2,...,N$. If we want to estimate a sample volatility, then we can use $$\sigma^2=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1}\sum(R_i-\mu_R)^2}$$, where $\mu_R$ is the average of the series.
However, if we have a daily data and we want to estimate daily volatility, in the literature it is used the following equation:
$$\sigma_t^2=R_t^2$$.
What is the connection of the first equation and the second? Why the latter is called a volatility? (Volatility is defined as deviation from them mean, but in the second estimation we do not have mean.) I do not understand the intuition of the second equation. Please explain. Thanks!

Comment: The mean is assumed to be zero, because usually it is very close to zero, and it makes modelling overall easier. Moreover, $\sigma_2 = \mathbb{E}[r_t^2] - \mathbb{E}[r_t]^2$ so if $\mathbb{E}[r_t]$ is small then $\mathbb{E}[r_t]^2$ is very small.

Comment: @rubikscube09, consider posting your comment as an answer.